# How to DIsplay images from Firebase Storage in React Native in using snapshot?

Tags: react-native

I am new at React Native and using Expo, I was able to successfully set up an app that uploads pictures to Firebase Storage, but now I'm having trouble showing those images on the app(Homescreen).

How do I pull/Display the latest images into a FlatList or similar scrollable component? I've looked through StackOverflow for previous answers, but have had no luck.
Thank you For Any Help!

HomeS.js:

```
export default class HomeS extends React. Component {

    renderPost = post => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.feedItem}>
                <Image source={post.avatar} style={styles.avatar} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.name}>{post.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.timestamp}>{moment(post.timestamp).fromNow()}</Text>
                        </View>

                        <Feather name="more-horizontal" size={24} color="#73788B"  /> 
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.post}>{post.text}</Text>
                    <Image source={post.image} style={styles.postImage} resizeMode="cover" />
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <Feather name="heart" size={24} color="#73788B" style={{marginRight:16}}  />
                        <Ionicons name="chatbox" size={24} color="#73788B" />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state=({
            posts:[],
            newtext:'',
            loading:false,
        });
        this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('posts').orderBy("timestamp", "desc");
        }
    
   
    componentDidMount() {

        const {imageName} = this.state;
        let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('photos' + imageName);
        imageRef
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
    //from url you can fetched the uploaded image easily
        this.setState({profileImageUrl: url});
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
        
        this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot => {
            const example = [];
            
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc, index)=>{
                example.push({
                    name: doc.data().name, //Work
                    id: doc.data().id,  //Work
                    text: doc.data().text,  //Work
                    timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,  //Work
                    imageRef: doc.data().imageRef // Not Working
                    
                   
                });
            });
            this.setState({
                posts:example,
                loading: false,
            });
        }));
    }
    

    onPressPost = () => {
        this.ref.add({
            textname : this.props.text,localUri: this.state.image

        }).then((data)=>{
            console.log(`adding data = ${data}`);
            this.setState({
                newtext:'',
                image:null,
                loading:true
            });
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(`error to add doc = ${error}`);
            this.setState({
                newtext:'',
                loading:true
            });
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Feed</Text>
                </View>

                <FlatList
                    style={styles.feed}
                    data={this.state.posts}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderPost(item)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                ></FlatList>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: anyone, please?

Comment: i will answer in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to display images in firebase storage you wil follow these steps:-

1. upload image to firebase
2. get download link
3. use download link in image source

first you will get file object from input type file

```
<input type="file" onchange={(e)=>(this.uploadImage(e))}
```

upload image & get download url

```
uploadImage = async (e) => {

    var files = e.target.files
    var image = files[0]

    const Buffer = await image.arrayBuffer() // convert img to buffer 

    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/MyPix')
    var picPath = "pic_awesome.jpg"
    var ref = storageRef.child(picPath)
    var metadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg', public: true }

    await ref.put(Buffer, metadata)
    var downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL()
    console.log('Download Url :: ' + downloadUrl)
    return downloadUrl;    
}
```

now display image from download url

```
 <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: this.state.ImageUrl}}
    />
```

now let me tell you a performant way of uploading mutiple images

```
const imageList = ['https://imgpath.jpg','https://imgpath2.jpg']

const requests = imageList.map((image) => {
    return uploadImage(image)  // upload image method is given above
})

console.log(`start uploading All images in imageList in parallel`)
  const response = await Promise.all(requests)
  response.map((image)=> saveToFireStore(image))
```

now save download url to firestore

```
 import { addDoc, collection , getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```

...

```
const saveToFireStore = async (downloadUrl) => {

const db = getFirestore();
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    userId: "123",
    userName: "Mathison",
    profilePic: downloadUrl
  });

}
```

now lets come to your final homejs component where we get images from frestore & display in listview

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
```

...

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    // get Images from Firestore & save To State

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        example.push({
            name: doc.data().name, //Work
            id: doc.data().id,  //Work
            text: doc.data().text,  //Work
            timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,  //Work
            imageRef: doc.data().profilePic // saved in saveToFireStore(): Working
        });
    })
    this.setState({
        posts:example,
        loading: false,
    });
}
```

now other methods render & renderPost will start working as they are because user object has images now

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Feed</Text>
            </View>

            <FlatList
                style={styles.feed}
                data={this.state.posts}
                renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderPost(item)}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ></FlatList>
        </View>
    );
}
```

display image from user object

```
renderPost = post => {
    return (
      <Image source = {{uri:post.imageRef}} /> 
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!, But I have another component it’s called PostScreen.js and there I upload the images to firebase and in component HomeScreen where I mentioned the problem there I need help to download the images and  show them on the screen. All the information is available but just the image after post upload is not showing, Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to save download link in your database to show images later

Comment: Ok...Can you please show an example or how to do that with my code? Thank You!!

Comment: getting download url is included.which database you are using ? firebase realtime or firestore ?

Comment: I am using firestore...on the storage I have a folder with all the photos that I uploaded

Comment: ok i will update answer in a while

Comment: Ok, Thank You, and if you can please see the code that I uploaded here on HomeS.js and there to update the answer or the example it will be very helpful!!

Comment: edit my answer & also Home.js component